# Toggle groups of comments in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a site right now where I frequently need to toggle between different states in my SCSS/JS files. As a very simple example, let's say I have a set of CSS parameters:

```
.selector{
     opacity: 1;
     pointer-events: all;
     transform: scale(1);
}
```

Multiple times a day, I'm having to manually go in and change it to

```
.selector{
     opacity: 0;
     pointer-events: none;
     transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

so that I can work on a particular section of the site. It would be great if I could set up a comment structure like so:

```
.selector{
     opacity: 0; //1;
     pointer-events: none; //all;
     transform: scale(0.5); //scale(1);
}
```

and quickly toggle these comments on/off to switch between states. Is there any kind of functionality or extension that enables something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen an extension that does what you ask - taking a value from a comment and overwriting code.  If you don't find something closer to what you want, an extension that I wrote could be helpful:  [Toggle Line Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments&ssr=false#overview).

[image: toggle comments extension]

Comment: This is great and will definitely work for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex Search Replace

Find

```
: ([^;]+); //([^;]+);
```

Replace

```
: $2; //$1;
```

You can place this search and replace in a keybinding.